# ipad scrollbar in html5

Tags: ipad, html, scroll, overflow

I am very new to HTML5 development for ipad. I am creating my first application for ipad using HTML5. Everything is done except I am facing one problem. Problem description is.

There is one vertical overflowing div. This page is viewed properly in computer's browser but when the same page is viewed in ipad the overflowing section is cutoff and it appears that there is no overflowing content.

Please let me know the proper way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

On the iPad scrollable `div`'s using `overflow` scrollbars will not appear on that div. The only way to scroll is using a two finger swipe.

Joe says that Scrollability is not yet ready to be used, so I wouldn't implement it in a production system.

To do this you have other options like:
http://cubiq.org/scrolling-div-on-iphone-ipod-touch

Answer (score 1):

You want native-like scrolling on the iPad in your HTML5 application? You might want to check out a project called Scrollability by Joe Hewitt: http://joehewitt.github.com/scrollability/

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://github.com/appmobi/aux_web (aUX_webScroll)  .  I'm the author, so if you have any questions, let me know.

iOS5 has the new property to allow scrolling on divs, but you'll find out that when you use it in a webview, the whole webview moves too and surprisingly, not everyone upgrades the OS.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote an article about new features in iOS 5. Also this topic is covered on section -webkit-overflow-scrolling: http://samuli.hakoniemi.net/ios-5-and-new-features-for-web-developers/#webkit-overflow-scrolling